# Tag synonym request: [version] -> [versions]

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Synonimization of singular/plural tag pairs](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3924/synonimization-of-singular-plural-tag-pairs)

We have both [version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/version) and [versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/versions) tags.

I recommend [version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/version) be made a synonym of [versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/versions). There are more questions in [versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/versions), and the plural is less awkward when asking questions about different *versions* of software (e.g., comparisons between, upgrading/downgrading from one to another, having 2+ installed/running simultaneously).

Comment: I wouldn't want to have both the tags. Can we do away with them please?

Comment: I second the motion.

Comment: This has been taken care of as part of [this meta thread](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3924/synonimization-of-singular-plural-tag-pairs). You can either delete it, close it or answer it yourself.