# Synonimization of singular/plural tag pairs

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There are a few [foo]/[foos] tag pairs on Ask Ubuntu. Such tag pairs are usually the singular and plural of the same word and should be synonyms. Occasionally.

Only moderators can create [foos] when [foo] exists or vice versa, but this wasn't the case when the site launched, so a few such pairs have crept in. [This query](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/72948/tags-with-similar-names) provides the complete list. Among these: [window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/window)/[windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows) and [synaptic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/synaptic)/[synaptics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/synaptics) are obviously coincidences. The others seem to be synonyms but I haven't looked very closely.

Please review that the following tag pairs are indeed synonyms. If they are, they should be merged. The number after each tag is the number of questions as of 2012-06-27 (the last data dump).

- [shortcut-keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/shortcut-keys) (672)    [shortcuts-keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/shortcuts-keys) (4)
- [users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/users) (151)    [user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/user) (73)
- [service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/service) (111)    [services](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/services) (16)
- [image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/image) (111)    [images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/images) (32)
- [codecs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/codecs) (58)    [codec](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/codec) (10)
- [color](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/color) (51)    [colors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/colors) (50)
- [speakers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/speakers) (47)    [speaker](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/speaker) (12)
- [versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/versions) (46)    [version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/version) (28)
- [distribution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/distribution) (38)    [distributions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/distributions) (2)
- [hostname](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hostname) (32)    [hostnames](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hostnames) (2)
- [tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/tool) (18)    [tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/tools) (15)
- [module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/module) (18)    [modules](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/modules) (13)
- [widgets](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/widgets) (16)    [widget](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/widget) (12)

Comment: They look good to me, i'll tackle those tonight if nobody objects.